# Backoff Strategy after hitting rate limits

Tags: node.js, rate-limiting, getstream-io, exponential-backoff

When you hit the rate limits on `getstream`, the APIs start responding with errors.

What is the recommended approach as a **backoff strategy** to handle those failures and start recovery after that. I thought about logging them all and send all of them again after a minute or hour.

But what if user created a post *(failed to be created on getstream, waiting for a backoff)* and meanwhile user deletes it. The backoff script will send the `post` to `getstream` even if user deleted it.

What is recommended by `getstream` or anyone handled the situation like that?

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, API rate-limit errors are typically handled with (exponential) backoff solutions.

This often involves additional application logic (flow control and queues) and special purpose data services / storage (message queues, async workers etc). This can add quite some complexity to an application.

When it comes to the Stream service, being rate-limited is usually an indication of either a flaw/deficiency in the implementation (much like a performance bug) or that the application has reached a scale that is beyond that the current plan is intended to support.

It'd be wise to contact Stream support directly about this.